# Flex Slider 2.2.0 error in IE8/7

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm Getting an error in IE8/7 : SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'addSlide' of undefined or null reference while using flex slider 2.2.0

Comment: You know you should add some source code to help your purpose..:)

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Basically, IE9 breaks flash ExternalInterface calls if your flash component is embedded with an object tag with an embed tag fallback, and the object id and embed name is the same.

The easiest workaround is to tell ie9 to render your page in IE8 Standards mode. To do this, insert this in the element:

```
<!-- Enable IE8 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Otherwise, you might just want to use the object tag only or embed tag only.